# Django BooleanField not returning value on post if default is given

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have this model:-

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    billing_same_as_mailing = models.BooleanField(default=True, label='...')
```

And this form:-

```
class ModelAForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        fields = ['billing_same_as_mailing']
```

And in my template I have tried the field with:-
    `{{ form.billing_same_as_mailing }}`

**Now when I post, the value of billing_same_as_mailing is always false in the cleaned_data.
But if I set the default value of the BooleanField as False in the model, everything works fine.**

Now when I inspect the checkbox element on the browser, this is what I get:-
**With default=False:-**

```
<input class="" id="billing_same_as_mailing" name="billing_same_as_mailing" type="checkbox">
```

**With default=True:-**

```
<input checked="checked" class="" id="id_billing_same_as_mailing" name="billing_same_as_mailing" type="checkbox" value="">
```

Why is this happening??

Comment: The rendered HTML looks fine. I would guess that the problem is with how you are checking/using the value in `cleaned_data`. Show us the code that doesn't work.

Comment: def form_valid(self, form):
        print form.cleaned_data

This shows that the value of billing_same_as_mailing is False

Comment: print form.cleaned_data['billing_same_as_mailing']

also returns False

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces your error - otherwise you are just asking is to shoot in the dark. In this case we need the view and template code that you're using to render and handle the form.

Comment: @AbhinavNair Do you override your save method anywhere ?

Comment: No I did not override it.

Answer (score 1):

I ultimately did this:-

```
<input type="checkbox" class="icheckbox" id="id_billing_same_as_mailing" name="billing_same_as_mailing" {% if form.billing_same_as_mailing.value %} checked="checked" {% endif %} value="{{ form.billing_same_as_mailing.value }}">{{ form.billing_same_as_mailing.label }}
```

This works perfectly fine.

From what I tried, on my system (running Django 1.9.8) the value of the input field was not populating to true.
When I tried on another system (running Django 1.7.3) the checked="checked" of the input field was not populating although the code is the same for both.

For some reason, either the checked or the value of the input field is not populating.

For the form to work properly, both the checked and value properties of the input element needs to be present.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: @ Abhinav Nair Hey thanks for the answer, but why is it that every radio-button appears, checked even when its not selected

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `value="on"` So the input element looks like this -

`<input type="checkbox" class="icheckbox" id="id_billing_same_as_mailing"  name="billing_same_as_mailing" {% if form.billing_same_as_mailing.value %} checked="checked" {% endif %} value="on">`

I tried rendering the form using one of the [default options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#form-rendering-options) Django provides and logging `request.POST` in the view. For a Boolean Field it is `{u'billing_same_as_mailing' : [u'on']}`.

Since this is a [model form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/), if we ensure that `request.POST` looks like what `ModelAForm` expects, it will map it to corresponding fields. You can use this method to check if you need to modify other input elements too